# Python how to write a new csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pycharm

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', usecols=[0,3,4,5,9])
print (df)
```

I only want to return these specific columns from my csv file and write it into a new csv file?

How can I do this

so far i can read the data!! but not sure how to write it

ABSOLUTE PYTHON BEGGINER ALERT

Comment: `df.to_csv('filename.csv')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your input, i assume you are trying to achieve something like this ?

```
#import library
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__

# read the csv with all columns
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
print (df)

# create csv with filtered columns
filter_cols = ["0","3","4","5","9"]
df.to_csv('output.csv', columns = filter_cols)
```